# Paypal Sandbox (express-checkout) return internal error

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

since yesterday evening i've a problem with my "express-checkout API"

Every time if I called the uri
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-0W349......

I get the error

---

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@paypal.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

---

Yesterday in the morning everything was ok and since I didn't change anything also nothing on the API class.
My Server support the sha256 and the protocol Tls12.

I've nothing in the Logfile from server.

The Live environment works fine but the sandbox environment doesn't work since yesterday.

Is it an error on paypal site or on my side?
I've send also a mail to paypal but I get an autoresponse Message.

Please help me and sry for my bad english.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: The sandbox environment is not that stable. I doubt you need worry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be related to the recent sandbox downtime over the past 24 hours or so. The problem was diagnosed by the team and they were able to repair the problem. Can you check again to see if it's working now please?

Comment: Yes now its working Thanks a lot for your Info and sry for my lae Answer.
Best regards